# Need help Google Apps Script and sheet: Building a custom function for Google spreadsheet to Copy/Paste Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm building a function to get Value from another cell. It will work this way:
At cell A1, I place function = copyValue(B1) or = copyValue(1 , 2) so that custom function will return the value of B1.
Here is my code:

```js
function copyValue(int a,b) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1HTEuyd7po43VKM37nmzCvPgLEVESgcN5YpAu2VRTiFI');
  var sheet =  ss.getSheetByName("Total");
  var cell = sheet.getRange(a,b);
  var c = cell.getValue();
  return(c);
}
```

But when I run, it said:
[quote]Missing ) after formal parameters. (line 1)[/quote]

if I remove "int" before the formal params, it said I cannot getRange NULL.
Please help me to fix this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your function much simpler if all you are trying to do is get the value of a cell.

```
function copyValue(cell) {
  return cell;
}
```

Then in your sheet just do `=copyValue(B1)` and whatever your value is in B1 will be returned into the cell.